# Composer - Autoload e PSR-0 vs PSR-4

Tags: php, composer, dependências, php-autoload

Estou começando a estudar Composer e estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde separo arquivos do core de arquivos da aplicação, da seguinte forma:

```
/ root 
    |-- /src 
         |-- /App 
               |-- /DBConfig
               |-- /Controller
               |-- /Model
         |-- /Core 
               |-- /Helper
               |-- /Controller
               |-- /Model
```

Então, para setar esta configuração no arquivo composer.json e conseguir ter acesso a todas as classes tanto de /App quanto de /Core, seria desta forma?

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-X" : {
        "App\\" : "/src",
        "Core\\" : "/src"
    }
}
```

Ou há uma forma mais correta?

Tenho lido, também, sobre **PSR-0 vs PSR-4** e ainda estou um pouco em dúvidas de qual utilizar. Neste meu caso qual devo implementar, **PSR-0 ou PSR-4**?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A diferença é que com a **PSR-0** o **autoloader** vai procurar uma pasta com o nome do namespace que você configurou dentro do diretório informado e com a **PSR-4** ele vai usar a pasta que você configurou como a pasta do próprio namespace.

Exemplo PSR-0:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Zend\\": "vendor"
        }
    }
}
```

O autoloader vai procurar a pasta `Zend`, correspondente ao namespace `Zend` dentro da pasta `vendor`. Exemplo, o namespace `\Zend\Acl\Acl`, vai corresponder ao arquivo 
`vendor/Zend/Acl/Acl.php`.

Se você tivesse configurado o caminho como `vendor/Zend` o arquivo que o autoloader tentaria carregar seria: `vendor/Zend/Zend/Acl/Acl.php`.

Exemplo PSR-4:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Zend\\": "vendor/Zend"
        }
    }
}
```

O autoloader vai usar a pasta `vendor/Zend` como a pasta do namespace `Zend`, o namespace `\Zend\Acl\Acl` vai corresponder ao arquivo `vendor/Zend/Acl/Acl.php`.

Outro exemplo PSR-4:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Zend\\": "algumacoisaqualquer/maisoutracoisaqualquer"
        }
    }
}
```

O autoloader vai usar a pasta `algumacoisaqualquer/maisoutracoisaqualquer` como a pasta do namespace `Zend`, o namespace `\Zend\Acl\Acl` vai corresponder ao arquivo `algumacoisaqualquer/maisoutracoisaqualquer/Acl/Acl.php`.

Fontes:

- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/
- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0

Answer (score 11):

Vai da situação. Caso o namespace vá para uma pasta onde a primeira nomenclatura é diferente, PSR-4.
Exemplo:

```
MyLib/
    LibComponents/
        Component1/
        Component2/
        ...
```

Porém a namespace desses components, em vez de começarem com MyLib, começam com Lib, dai você especifica no Composer:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Lib\\": "vendor/some-lib/some-lib/libs/MyLib/"
        }
    }
}
```

Acredito que não há uma forma mais correta, vai da necessidade.

**No seu caso:**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/App/",
            "Core\\": "src/Core/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... Entendi. Então, creio que ficaria melhor se criasse um diretório intermediário tipo: /src/Project/App/Controller/, então o autoload ficaria apenas "Project\\": "src/". Que acha?

Comment: Também é uma boa. Aliás, acredito que melhor do que você estava fazendo antes.