# "Novo" autoload do PHP 7

Tags: php, php-autoload, autoload

Gostaria de entender o "novo" autoload do PHP, nele eu posso escolher o nome que quero colocar?

Por exemplo, no antigo, era `__autoload`. Esse no caso, eu posso colocar `autoload_de_teste` ?

Outra dúvida é o que faz o spl_autoload_register e onde coloco ele no meu arquivo? No final do método do autoload?

Autoload antigo:

```
function __autoload($Class){
    $P = ['Conn'];
    $Incluido = null;

    foreach ($P as $Pasta) {
        if(!$Incluido && file_exists(__DIR__ . "\\{$Pasta}\\{$Class}.class.php") && !is_dir(__DIR__ . "\\{$Pasta}\\{$Class}.class.php")):
            include_once __DIR__ . "\\{$Pasta}\\{$Class}.class.php";
            $Incluido = true;
        else:
            trigger_error("Erro ao incluir: " . __DIR__ . "\\{$Pasta}\\{$Class}.class.php");
            die;
        endif;
    }
}
```

O Novo ficaria assim, por exemplo:

```
function autoload_de_teste($Class){
    $P = ['Conn'];
    $Incluido = null;

    foreach ($P as $Pasta) {
        if(!$Incluido && file_exists(__DIR__ . "\\{$Pasta}\\{$Class}.class.php") && !is_dir(__DIR__ . "\\{$Pasta}\\{$Class}.class.php")):
            include_once __DIR__ . "\\{$Pasta}\\{$Class}.class.php";
            $Incluido = true;
        else:
            trigger_error("Erro ao incluir: " . __DIR__ . "\\{$Pasta}\\{$Class}.class.php");
            die;
        endif;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register("autoload_de_teste");
```

Essa é a dúvida no caso, a função do `spl_autoload_register` e onde devo coloca-lo, (por exemplo, início do arquivo, ou no final do método de autolod, etc...) e se nesse jeito de fazer, se posso colocar qualquer nome.

Answer (score 7):

> Gostaria de entender o "novo" autoload do PHP[...]

Novo em partes. O autoload através da função [`spl_register_autoload`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) está disponível desde a versão [5.1.2 do PHP](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.1.2) (12 de Janeiro de 2006). E, mesmo assim, existem implementações da função no lançamento da versão [5.1.0](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.1.0).

**__autoload**

Voltando ao "cerne" da questão. A função `[__autoload][4]` foi a primeira a existir no PHP e existe desde o lançamento da versão [5.0.0 do PHP](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.1.0) (13 de Julho de 2004).

Basicamente, deve-se criar uma função com o nome `__autoload` (similar aos [métodos mágicos](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), mas pertencente ao escopo global e não a uma classe).

Como é pertencente ao escopo global, você pode apenas criar uma única função de autoload. Ou seja, todas as regras de autoload deveriam estar contidas em um único lugar.

É importante ressaltar que `namespaces` só foi implementado à partir da versão [5.3.0 do PHP](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0). Entre a versão 5.0.0 e 5.3.0, foram 5 anos de desenvolvimento e muitas especulações (possuo literaturas informando que separação entre namespacess seria `::` ao invés de `\`).

**O problema**

Logo no início do lançamento do PHP 5, com a novidade de *autoload*, muitas bibliotecas também passaram a utilizar o `__autoload`. Entretanto, foi percebida uma limitação com o uso de *namespace*. Uma aplicação que utilizava o `__autoload` [não poderia utilizar uma biblioteca](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php#75832) que também utilizava o `__autoload`. Isso era um grande motivo de conflito com bibliotecas terceiras (*third-party*).

**spl_autoload_register**

Por outro lado, `spl_autoload_register` permite serem "registrados" quantos *autoloads* forem necessários. Nesse caso, o PHP irá executar cada *autoload* (na ordem em que foram registrados, padrão *[Chain Of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_of_responsibility)*) até conseguir carregar a classe solicitada ou todas as opções se esgotarem.

Dessa forma, bibliotecas terceiras não teriam mais problemas em implementar seu próprio autoload. Pois, como não haviam regras que definissem como uma classe devesse estar nomeada e qual *file path* deveria possuir, era bem comum cada biblioteca ter sua própria convenção de como carregar uma classe.

Anos mais tarde, houve a definição conhecida como [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) e, algum tempo depois, [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), as quais normalizaram a forma que uma classe deve implementar um *namespace* e ser definida em um *file path*.

Mesmo assim, possuindo as PSR's, ainda é possível encontrar diferenças entre *namespace* de bibliotecas diferentes, principalmente a diferença entre *namespace* que são omitidos do caminho físico (*file path*) e existem como *namespace* lógicos (apenas nas classes0. O qual você pode verificar no link abaixo:

[Composer - Autoload e PSR-0 vs PSR-4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32606/5007)

> [...]o spl_autoload_register [...] onde coloco ele no meu arquivo? No final do método do autoload?

Em qualquer lugar. O único detalhe é que, a função, ou classe, que for ser utilizada como *autoload* já deve existir.

Tanto que, bibliotecas terceiras carregavam seu próprio *autoload* apenas quando executada/incluída no projeto (`require`/`include`). Essa questão acabou sendo tratada com o uso do *autoload* do *composer*, que carrega todos os *autoloads* juntos.

**Quando e o que usar?**

Sem dúvida nenhuma, a resposta será sempre a mesma. Se sua versão de PHP for igual ou superior a 5.1.2, utilize sempre `spl_autoload_register`. Senão, bom, não há escolha, existe apenas `__autoload`. Outro detalhe é que a função `__autload` foi descontinuada (*deprecated*) na versão 7.2.0 do PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php

> **Warning** This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Como dica, ao invés de criar seu próprio *autoload*, recomendo o uso do *autoload* gerado pelo *composer*. Rápido, fácil e otimizado, não lhe deixa na mão.