# Problema para instanciar classe

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou criando um aplicação MVC onde há injeção de dependência para instanciar as classes com conexão com o banco de dados, o problema se dá quando subi a aplicação para um servidor remoto, quando tento acessar recebo o seguinte erro
"Uncaught Error: Class '\App\Models\Registros' not found in ..."

o Erro propriamente dito está no arquivo Container.php

```
namespace SON\DI;

    class Container
    {
        public static function getClass($name)
        {
            $str_class = "\\App\\Models\\".ucfirst($name);
            $class = new $str_class(\App\Init::getDb());
            return $class;
        }
    }
```

Ele é chamado na classe SubmissaoController

```
$registros = \SON\DI\Container::getClass("Registros");
```

Segue também a classe Registro.php análoga a todas as outras classes Model que utilizariam da Injeção

```
namespace App\Models;

class Registros {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct (\PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
```

O curioso é que o código funciona em local mas não está funcionando no host, já revirei fóruns mas não obtive resposta.

Comment: Não faltou subir esse arquivo para o servidor? Ele é inserido na página executada?

Comment: Sim, ele está no servidor, não entendi o inserido na página, você quis dizer o quê? dar um include nele?

Comment: Sim `include` ou `require` ou usando autoload

Comment: a aplicação tem aquele autoload do composer que é criado quando a gente dá install pelo cmd, mas eu não entendi como exatamente ela funciona, ou se tenho que aplicar alguma coisa no servidor a respeito

Comment: Você deve configurar a propriedade `psr-4` do `composer.json` (de uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19200/composer-autoload-e-psr-0-vs-psr-4)) deve ser esse o problema. Também não esqueça de executar o `composer dump-autoload` para atualizar o autoload

Comment: tá ok, vou fazer, Mas eu não tenho acesso ao ssh do servidor remoto portanto eu posso fazer o cump-autoload aqui em local e transmitir os arquivos para o servidor? ou eu preciso realmente dar um jeito de conseguir o ssh?

Comment: Não precisa, só fazer em local e depois passar os arquivos para o remoto

Comment: Executei os passos do autoload inserindo da seguinte forma,                   {
 "name": "son/mvc",
 "require": {
  "php": ">=5.3"
 },

 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "SON\\": "vendor/SON/",
   "App\\": "App/"
    }
  },
 "config": {
  "bin-dir": "bin"
 }
}

Comment: mesmo com os comandos e o upload no server continuo com o problema da classe

Comment: Na realidade o problema estava ligado ao .Htacess do servidor, ele fazia o Autoload funcionar de forma errada, após altera-lo consegui fazer funcionar.

Comment: Já que resolveu o problema, poste uma resposta com o arquivo antes e depois da correção explicando. Irá ajudar futuros usuários que tiverem o mesmo problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o código contido no .htacess é

```
RewriteEngine On
```

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]